# Long Press: BAD_EXC_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

Here is my code:

```
@interface UserProfileViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation UserProfileViewController

@synthesize myLabel;
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];
myLabel.text = @"Kim Gysen";
myLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)/2.0f, 25);
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 180)];
self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)/2.0f, 150);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ProfilePic.jpeg"];
[imageView setImage:image];

//Long press

self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressFrom:)];
longPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];

[scrollView addSubview:myLabel];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

}

- (void) handleLongPressFrom: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    NSLog(@"Tap Gesture Coordinates: %.2f %.2f", location.x, location.y);
    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == recognizer.state)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Gesture Recognizer Demo"
                                                        message:@"Long Press Gesture performed"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

I get no errors in my ViewDidLoad, but the BAD_EXC_ACCESS error appears on the long press, before the method is actually fired. I understood that I'm leaking somewhere but where? 
I'm using ARC...

Comment: Hmm.... I made a new project (from the single view template) and added you code to the ViewController.h and .m -- it worked just fine.  BTW, the BAD_EXC_ACCESS error doesn't have anything to do with leaks, you usually get it from accessing a deallocated instance of something. How are you instantiating your UserProfileViewController?

Comment: What I use is: UserProfileViewController *profileView = [[UserProfileViewController alloc] init];
            [self.view addSubview: profileView.view]; where self is the main ViewController where I add and remove subviews. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a property in your main view controller (typed strong) that points to the ProfileViewController then use:

```
self.profileView = [[UserProfileViewController alloc] init]; 
[self.view addSubview: self.profileView.view];
```

Comment: Huray to you. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have an Additional question. Actually, it works for [self.View addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer]; but not when I use self.imageView (instance of UIImageView. Is that normal? I don't use IB.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot: self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;